# Python, creating multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create 10 files named `prgram1.py , program2.py , ... , program10.py` but this code runs only once

My code:

```
def create():
    num = 0
    num = num + 1
    program = open("program" + str(num) + ".py","w")
```

What is wrong whit this code? What changes should I make?

Comment: Might wanna fix your indentation

Comment: Can you add other informations about your problem?

Comment: In this example, `num` is always 1 and you keep creating a new "program1.py" each time you call it.

Comment: It would be helpful to include a statement of what you want to happen.

Comment: Thanks. My question was a little dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please learn to post standard questions in StackOverflow. Specially specify your question.

Assuming that you want to create multiple files, let's say 10 files (num 1 to 10), you need to make a loop somewhere. I suggest you to keep your `create` function for creating one file.

function:

```
def create(num):
    program = open("program" + str(num) + ".py", "w")
```

and for the loop:

```
# range(1,11) -> [1,2,3,4,...,10]    
for i in range(1,11):
        create(i)
```

or

```
i = 1
while(i <= 10):
    create(i)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop, a for loop, a while loop or a forever loop.

I've put a forever loop here, but this will try to create infinite files, so I've slowed him down a bit.

```
import time

def create():
    num = 0
    while True:
        num = num + 1
        program = open("program" + str(num) + ".py","w")
        time.sleep(1) # 1 second sleep before each one.
```